# Python: Return hash values from hash table regarding to a searching keyword

Tags: python, python-2.7, hash

I'm new to python. I'm learning to get data from hash table which is stored in a file. 
I want to retrieve key and values regarding an input keyword. This should be return as dictionary. This is an example of the table:

```
{ 
"Technology": {"20809": 98},
"Movie":{"1193435": 1},
"Entertainment":{"13398": 76},
"Computer": {"28765": 54},
"Food": {"708": 4},
"Gasoline": {"358": 18},
"Material": {"98": 6},
"Water": {"3": 6}
}
```

This is a function I have written.

```
def searchAtHashTable(input):        
    ind = # I read the hash value from a file by using .read()
    for key in ind.keys():
        if key == input:
            return sorted(ind.get(key))
```

I want to return a dict like {"Entertainment":{"13398": 76}} when I search for the word "Entertainment".Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply construct a dictionary dynamically using the key and the actual value retrieved from the original dictionary, like this

```
data = { 
"Technology": {"20809": 98},
"Movie":{"1193435": 1},
"Entertainment":{"13398": 76},
"Computer": {"28765": 54},
"Food": {"708": 4},
"Gasoline": {"358": 18},
"Material": {"98": 6},
"Water": {"3": 6}
}

def searchAtHashTable(input):
    return {input : data.get(input, {})}

print searchAtHashTable("Entertainment")
```

**Output**

```
{'Entertainment': {'13398': 76}}
```

Comment: Well just a quick question. If I want to get the sub key and values of the sub key, what is the command? I want to get:
1. Only sub key of Entertainment  which is is 13398. 
2. The value of the sub keys Entertainment which is 76. 

I have tried variable.get(key) but I got both of sub key and sub key's values. thx